# How re-open a issue using commit?

Tags: git, github, commit

How re-open a issue using commit?
How can i do that? I know i can fix a issue in my commit (e.g. `fix #10`), but how re-open?

Best regards
Appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github has very simple rights/privileges (and even simpler management for them).

If you are not a collaborator of a repo, then (in regards to issues)

- you can open issues
- you can comment on all existing issues (open or closed)
- you can close your own issues
- you can re-open your own issues *if you closed them yourself
- you cannot close or re-open issues opened by someone else
- you cannot re-open your own issues if a repo collaborator closed them

The situation you report falls in the last case, so you cannot reopen it. You can ask in the issue thread if a repo collaborator can reopen it, or you can open a new issue and reference the old one (by mentioning its number preceded by a hash sign, e.g. #1189).

Answer (score 3):

To the best of my knowledge GitHub does not have this capability. The [help center documentation](https://help.github.com/categories/commits/) for commits does not have an article on doing this, so I believe the capability does not exist.

Comment: Indeed, because that make no sense to do such a thing.

Comment: I'd agree, you make commits to 'fix' or 'add' things...not to 'break' things.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense to do such a thing, though it's rare. Commit A fixes issue 1. Later, issue 2 is discovered, which was inadvertently caused by commit A. Issue 2 is more severe than issue 1, so commit B is created to simply revert commit A, which fixes issue 2 but reopens issue 1. Issue 1 will be resolved at a later time without reintroducing issue 2. I ran into this today, probably for the first time in my years using GitHub. It's no big deal to manually reopen the issue, but it would be nice if GitHub had this capability.